# Interchanging negative confidence limits

Tags: confidence-interval

I know this may seems basic but I computed excess mortality in a straight forward way. But I am beginning to question what seems like a straight forward approach based on the result I obtained.

Here are my calculations and the issue at hand:

```
  baseline  rate  0.48[0.33,   0.72]

  Observed  rate 0.30[0.20,  0.50]
```

excess rate = observed rate - baseline rate

```
-0.18 [-0.13, - 0.22] **  this where my doubts set in.
```

I presented the result as follow  -0.18 [ -0.22, -0.13]  which seems obvious reading it off a number line.

However, is this approach with reversing the confidence limits correct or is there something I am missing?